# Get the height of two nested boxes dynamically with jquery height?

Tags: jquery, css, height

I want to get the height of a box (yellow background in my example) dynamically - depending on the length of its content. So if it has a long text, its height will increase. And this yellow box has a parent container (blue background in my example).

What I don't understand is why they have the same height - which is `100`?

The blue box should have higher number as it has **padding top 20px** and **padding bottom 20px**. So the blue box should have **140** if the yellow box is **100**.

jquery,

```
// Set the object.
var object = $(".box");
//var object_height = parseInt(object.css('min-height'),10) || parseInt(object.css('height'),10);
var object_height = object.height();

var scrollable = $(".scrollable");
//var scrollable_height = parseInt(scrollable.css('min-height'),10) || parseInt(scrollable.css('height'),10);
var scrollable_height = scrollable.height();

alert(object_height);
alert(scrollable_height);
```

html,

```
<div class="box">

    <div class="scrollable">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

link from [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTgvm/).

Any ideas how to get this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `outerHeight()` method, it calculates height + margin/padding

Answer (score 1):

You can use `outerHeight()` method.

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns an integer (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

```
object.outerHeight()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GMtBa/

Answer (score 1):

You should use `outerHeight()` to get the proper height values.

```
// Set the object.
var object = $(".box");
var object_height = object.outerHeight();

var scrollable = $(".scrollable");
var scrollable_height = scrollable.outerHeight();

alert(object_height);
alert(scrollable_height);
```